# Extract particular value from the variable

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want just know how to extract the value from the variable in shell script.
following is the code:

```
var=Volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
```

or

```
var=Volume: 0: 35% 1: 35%
```

I want to extract 100 or 35 depends value from the variable and store it into another variable.
so how can i do this?

Comment: Which 100? There are two. And I assume both of these (being "variables" can be something other than 100, right?

Comment: @Oli - right. I want any 100

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you want as a result. Say you have the above line, what are you expecting. From what you've said you could `[[ $var == *100* ]] && temp=100` (if $var contains 100, set temp=100). That doesn't seem useful to me.

Comment: @Oli - I want to extract 100 from the variable and store it into another variable.

Comment: @Oli Also I have edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what the command you looking for,

```
sed 's/.*\ \(.*\)%.*/\1/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'var=Volume: 0: 35% 1: 35%' | sed 's/.*\ \(.*\)%.*/\1/g'
35

$ echo 'Volume: 0: 35% 1: 35%' | sed 's/.*\ \(.*\)%.*/\1/g'
35

$ var="Volume: 0: 35% 1: 35%"
$ echo $var | sed 's/.*\ \(.*\)%.*/\1/g'
35
```

This command will display the first number `35` or `100` before the first % mark.

Answer (score 3):

I think your target is a bit misguided so I've done what I would expect to want to do, split the values out into separate values.

```
var="Volume: 0: 70% 1: 12%"
source <(echo "$var" | grep -oP '\d+\: \d+' | sed -r 's/([0-9]+)\: /vol\1=/g')
```

So for every input volume, there is a `vol#` variable created. In the above, `echo $vol1` would be `70`, and `echo $vol2` gives `12`.

If `var="Volume: 0: 70% 1: 12% 2: 12% 3: 41% 4: 19%"`, you'll end up with five separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

If:

```
var="Volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%"
```

then:

- to extract first `100` you can use:

  ```
  temp=$(awk -F": |%" '{print $3}' <<< "$var")
  ```
- to extract last `100` you can use:

  ```
  temp=$(awk -F": |%" '{print $5}' <<< "$var")
  ```
- to extract both `100` you can use:

  ```
  temp=$(awk -F": |%" '{print $3, $5}' <<< "$var")
  ```

Comment: for example var="Volume: 0: 70% 1: 70%" then how can extract 70 from this variable. your above answer is work only  for var="Volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%"